# RSACryptoServiceProvider and Web.config encryption

Tags: asp.net, cryptography

I am new to cryptography. I want to encrypt the connection string section and some other section in the web.config. I know this can be accomplished using RSACryptoServiceProvider.
But I am not sure about the Key which is being used by the default RSACryptoServiceProvider and the key size. 
As per our organization security policy the key size should be 196 bit and we have to share the Key with security team which is used for encryption.

When we use the default encryption what will be key used internally by asp.net for encryption/decryption and the key size?

In-order to use a custom key which can be shared with security team do we need to create a custom class by inhering RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Also RSA Key Container is bit confusing. Is it a container for the Key or the Key itself

Please advice.

Comment: Please see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

RSA key container files which are exported from aspnet_regiis.exe are indeed containers for the key.  They are XML files.  Actually, as RSA is public key crypto, the key container holds both the public key and private key (if you export both).

When you perform web.config or app.config encryption via aspnet_regiis.exe, and you do not specify a provider, it will use the value of "defaultProvider".  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100).aspx.  The encrypted output will list the provider name (so that you know how to decrypt it).  It appears the default name of the default provider is "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider".  That crypto provider uses a key.  The default key has a default name of "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mosharaf/archive/2005/11/17/protectedconfiguration.aspx).  The key with that name will have a different value on every machine and is generated when .NET is installed.

A key length of 196 bits sounds like your security team expects you to be performing symmetric key encryption (not asymmetric PKC) of some sort.  For example, people brag about their AES key lengths being 256 bits.  The .NET 4.0 aspnet_regiis.exe command for creating a custom RSA crypto provider and key use a key size of 2048 bits (although 1024 is not uncommon from days of yore).  I imagine the default RSA provider and default key use default values for key lengths.  But to be sure, you might want to export the default key, and inspect it yourself.  The -pc and -px switches and their associated options (like -size) are documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx.

If you need to be very specific about a private key, which would be durable beyond a machine reimaging, and would be used by many nodes in a server farm, and which needs to be held in escrow by the security team, you probably want to invest the time in creating a non-default crypto provider of the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider type (not inventing your own CSP class as an alternative to RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider).

One last thing to note, web.config XML encryption is performed in a multi step process.  First, the encryption process generates a random symmetric key (which is short in comparison to an RSA key) which will be used to encrypt a plaintext corpus.  The plaintext is encrypted with the symmetric key (after the corpus is normalized for whitespace, etc).  Then, the symmetric key (which is short compared to the corpus) is encrypted using an RSA public key.  If the whole plaintext corpus was encrypted with an RSA public key, it would take a long time to decrypt.  So when you look at a block of encrypted XML in a web.config encrypted you will really see two things: an encrypted key section, and an encrypted data section.  To decrypt the ciphertext, ASP.NET needs to first decrypt the encrypted symmetric key, and then use the decrypted key to decrypt the stuff you actually want as plaintext.

There is an example of the two-levels of encryption at "[Problem with decrypting xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700949/problem-with-decrypting-xml-document/20574871#20574871/)".  What is apparent (and perhaps troubling), is that the RSA crypto provider uses Triple DES in CBC mode for the symmetric crypto algorithm underlying the RSA PKC which you think is really providing the encryption.  See this person's frustration around trying to change the symmetric algorithm to AES, for example, [Change Microsoft Config File Encryption Method From TripleDES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797030/change-microsoft-config-file-encryption-method-from-tripledes).  Triple DES is only recommended for use until 2030 in very ideal scenarios (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Security) by the algorithm's endorsers (NIST).  NIST had a bake-off years ago for a replacement symmetric algorithm suite, which they have chosen and endorsed as AES (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).  So to use AES-192 or AES-256, you would need to invent your own CSP class as an alternative to RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, then make it available for creating providers and performing encrypt/decrypt operations from ASP.NET.

Here is another stack-overflow article which is relevant: [ASP.NET Encryption - aspnet_regiis - Farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998666/asp-net-encryption-aspnet-regiis-farm).

Here is a guide to creating/exporting RSA crypto providers and keys for spreading around in a farm, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There is a lot of amazing content in this answer which covers a wide variety of things. For anyone who is new to cryptography or with asp.net, the links shared in this article are worth going through and understanding!